# Netbeans using gcc unable to find standard header files after linux upgrade

Tags: linux, file, netbeans, header, upgrade

I'm developing a C application using Netbeans 7.1.2 on an IBM ThinkPad Edge 64-bit with a Core 2 Duo processor. I just upgraded from Linux Mint 9 to Linux Mint 14, and now Netbeans cannot find many of the standard header files needed to build my project. Before the Linux upgrade everything ran fine. I've tried looking at the paths Netbeans uses to search for standard header files for two versions of Netbeans, and they are identical. Is it likely that the location of those header files varies between distributions, or is their location part of the GNU standard (or maybe a Linux standard)? I suppose if no other solution is found, I could simply revert back to the older operating system, but I'm trying to avoid that. How can I tell if my Linux distro simply has an issue pertaining to its GNU header file location? I've tried searching in my entire file system for the first header file that wasn't found. I found it, copied it to one of the directories in Netbeans' header file path, but it simply complained about another one not found, and somehow that approach felt wrong. So, I tried to add the directory where I found the first unfound header to Netbeans' header file path, which again simply caused it to complain of other unfound headers. There must be something else going here. I appreciate any helpful information anyone could offer.

Answer (score 1):

mint 14 has all of the standard header files in the usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/ folder instead of the usr/include/sys folder as I believe the set up was in prior editions.  Point netbeans to the right location and you should be fine.